# SVG font-face with TTF fonts

Tags: html, fonts, svg, font-face, truetype

I'm trying to make use of the font-face elements of the SVG standard. At the moment Webkit claims that they implement the font module properly, but I can't get it to work with external referenced TTF files.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <font-face font-family="blabla">
      <font-face-src>
        <font-face-uri xlink:href="/path/to/font.ttf" />
      </font-face-src>
    </font-face>
  </defs>
  <text font-family="blabla">This doesn't work unfortunately</text>
</svg>
```

The above example doesn't work, using an embedded style tag with `@font-face {}` in the SVG document does work however. What am I doing wrong? (Considering this SVG document to be inlined in a HTML5 document.)

If this is actually possible, would this be possible through JavaScript aswell (font loading)?

Comment: If it works when you add with CSS, why not just use CSS?

Comment: Because I prefer using a more "native" implementation, and if it should work, I'd like to know why it does not.

Comment: This question encouraged me to try SVG fonts, but I couldn't get them working on any browser. The reason: They've been deprecated universally. ☹ http://caniuse.com/#search=svg%20fonts

Answer (score 1):

In theory your example should work, but I don't think any browsers have implemented `<font-face-uri>` except for SVG Fonts. A possible reason for this might be that no other font formats were required by the SVG 1.1 spec, and because of that there were mostly tests in w3c's svg testsuite using the SVG Font format.

But it's nothing wrong to use css @font-face, support for @font-face is required from all svg user agents that support CSS for styling svg content, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/fonts.html#FontDescriptionsAlternatives. That includes all currently shipping web browsers with svg support.

Comment: I know @font-face does it's job pretty well, but still I wonder why Webkit claims that they support [`font-face-uri`](http://www.webkit.org/projects/svg/status.xml), but it doesn't work at all.